# Override Taxonomy Pages without entire page override

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I need to override Taxonomy page (page--taxonomy--term.tpl.php) and wondering if it's possible to just override the content section of the page instead of the whole page.

I don't want to print all other regions again as I will to update different page tpls if I update some other part of the page template.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cool contributed module tvi (Taxonomy Views Integrator) refer 
URL: https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi for customizing the taxonomy view page and based on vocabularies you can change.

Thanks